# Built-in webcam not recognized

Tags: debian, camera

I have a Dell Inspiron 5547 (500 Series) running Debian Jessie 64 bits.

My lsusb output is:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My `dmesg | grep 'video'` output is:

```
[    6.138288] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    6.240522] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

I have installed v4l and loaded the uvcvideo module But, Cheese says "No device video found".

**UPDATE 1**

`ls -l /dev/video*` (the file o directory doesn't exist).

```
ls: no se puede acceder a /dev/video*: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

I tried running Cheese as root but, is the same result.

A more complete dmesg output:

```
[    5.916313] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    5.949843] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    6.018736] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    6.018739] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    6.186941] systemd-udevd[182]: starting version 215
[    7.995104] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000004040-0x000000000000405F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000004040-0x000000000000404F (\_SB_.PCI0.SBUS.SMBI) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[    7.995111] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Using `grep` will miss possible error messages. Please post the complete part from `dmesg`, from when the USB device is connected to the last related action. What's the output of `ls -l /dev/video*`? Do you have permission to use it?

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for reply. I updated my question.

Comment: So far, it looks like your webcam doesn't show up at all: Googling finds` 8087:07dc` is a bluetooth controller, and `8087:8000` is a "rate matching hub". What you see in `dmesg` are just generic initialization messages. And if it doesn't show up, of course there's no `/dev/video*`. Is there a key combination to turn the webcam on? Do the status lights change if you use it? Does it turn up in `lsusb` after that?

Comment: @dirkt There isn't a key to enable/disable webcam :(

Comment: Is it possible that the webcam is not a USB device? Have you run it under Windows, and if yes, what does the hardware device manager say about the webcam?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop/Dell#Inspiron says the webcam is supported, so I would check that the hardware actually works (under Windows, for example). [Elsewhere I've read](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/p/19520151/20718375#20718375) that its USB cable can get loose after lots of opening/closing the laptop lid.